# SSH into Linux Guest Virtual machine from External Source?

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualization

I currently have a Linux server running as a guest on Virtualbox using Windows 8.1 as the host. I can SSH from my Windows host into the guest with no problem. But how do I set it up so I can SSH from an external machine that is not within the local network, like from another country, for example? All the examples I see online are SSHing from the host to the guest only.

My Linux guest is using a bridged network and using dynamic IP.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use NAT and port forwarding using your host's external interface.

Comment: Port forwarding from the router or in Windows itself?

Comment: I'm not familiarized with VirtualBox version for MS Windows, but... on my GNU/Linux box when I run my VM i can reach network settings in VBox menu: Device/Network/Network Settings, then for Adapter 1 (NAT in my case) i pick 'Port forwarding' and then I match host and guest IPs and ports... For example i pick guest IP 10.0.2.15 and port 80 and forward it to host's port 31080 and my external IP (which I won't provide here for security reasons ;) ) After that and some host firewall customization guest service is available 'worldwide' via hosts interface.

Comment: Port forwarding from both: your router must forward a port to a port on your MS Windows host, and your MS Windows host must forward the port to your Linux guest. Even better: have your MS Windows host bridge the guest's IP stack, instead of doing NAT, so that your router can assign an IP address directly to the guest, and then the only port forwarding that needs to happen is on the router.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I guess I'd need to set up a static IP for that?

Comment: Pretty much. Most consumer-grade routers allow their internal DHCP server to be set up to map specific MAC addresses to fixed IP addresses. This gets combined with a port forwarding rule.

Comment: I must be missing something but I'm still having issues. Let me re-cap through the steps: 1. Setup a static IP address in the Linux guest. 2. Open a port in the Windows firewall (eg: 3456) for TCP and UDP connections. 3. Open the same port number (3456) in the network router for the IP address of the Linux guest. 4. Keep the network adaptor as 'bridged' network in the Virtualbox settings. Am I missing anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I got it figured out!

I set up 2 networks in Virtualbox: NAT (eth0) and bridged (eth1). NAT allows for internet access from the Linux guest, and bridged allows the Windows host to send the data through to the Linux guest. Both are given dynamic IP in the Linux guest.

In the port forwarding section for NAT of Virtualbox, I have the interal IP address of the Windows host and the IP address of the bridged connection as guest. In my case, it's 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.8, respectively. Ports are 2222 and 22, respectively.

For my router, I enabled port forwarding to port 2222 of the Windows host (192.168.1.1).

In Windows Firewall, I opened up port 2222 for connections.

And that's it! I can now SSH to the Linux guest from computers in the local network via (username)@192.168.1.8, and via (username)@Windows_host_public_IP from a computer outside the local network.

Answer (score 0):

I followed all the steps which you mentioned but still I am not able to connect from external network.

Steps I followed listed below.

1. Created NAT and Bridged connection on Linux vm.
2. Created NAT and Bridged connection on virtual box.
3. In NAT port forwarding table of virtual box, added host ip as windows ip and host port as 2222 along with guest ip as Linux vm Bridged ip and guest port as 22.
4. Opened port 2222 on windows firewall settings.

Please let me know if I missed something here.